# How to get response in json object using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using NodeJs and MongoDb as a back-end service.I have several documents in my collection having field named _id and Name.

I want to get Output in Json objects like below:

```
[ 
  {   
    Name:"Paul"
  },
  {   
    Name:"Jon"
  }
]
```

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');    
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})); 

app.post('/offers',(req, res) => {

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {           
if(err) throw err;
var dbo = db.db('Tiffino_db');

dbo.collection("Offers")
    .find({},{ projection: { _id: 0 } })
    .toArray((err, result) => {
         if (err) {
                 console.log("Error:", +err);
             }
             else { 
                 output =  result.map(r => r.Name);
                 res.json({"Name":output});
                 db.close();
            }
       });
   });
});
```

Here is my Output:

```
{
"Name": [
    "Paul",
    "Jon",
    "David",
    "Aina"
  ]
}
```

Please let me know how to modify code to get desired output.

**THANKS**

Comment: "I want to get Output in Json objects like below" — That is not JSON.

Comment: Consider using mongoose package https://mongoosejs.com/ it will make your life a lot easier working with mongodb

Comment: @kay how can i get using Mongodb driver

Comment: Can u tell me what exactly is inside `result`

Comment: @ArayniMax is right, you need to know what result has and then probably loop it to obtain the Array you desire.

Comment: I am getting an array  as output i have posted.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this

```
res.json({"Name":output})
```

Use this code

```
var json=    output.map(element=>{
    return {"Name":element.Name};
});
```

Comment: `element.Name`, else you return the entire query result under the name field instead of only the name string.

Comment: Sory I forgot it

Comment: @Shilly you are right, your code using arrow function of ES6 and my code doesn’t

Comment: Your code uses an arrow as well, the full specific ES5 version is `var json=  output.map(function(element){
    return {"Name":element.Name};
});` without an arrow. Anyways, take care.

Comment: Hehehe @Shilly you are right again but this time I know that,

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

`output = result.map(r => r.Name); res.json({"Name":output});`

Try:

`output = result.map( r => ({ "Name": r.Name })); res.json( output );`

As written, you map all the resulting records into one array, then assign that array to the property name. Instead you want to create a new object with the property name every time and return that array.

Comment: Thanks Shilly :), it gets result what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the  code you provided. With the collection structure and the query if you remove the line `output =  result.map(r => r.Name);` and just return `result` you will get the structure:

`[{ "Name": "TestName" },
  { "Name": "TestNam2" }]`

Then the code inside the `else` block would look like this:

```
res.json(result);
db.close();
```